# Is spark's read requests to HDFS load balanced?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, load-balancing

I am trying to understand how the communication between spark and HDFS works when we pull some data to spark. I have 4 datanodes and 5 spark workers. I see that when I run some computation on a dataset of 100 GB on HDFS it looks like each worker fetches data for a partition, waits for a moment likely due to processing and then repeats but with a different datanode.

What I am interested to know is whether Spark/HDFS have some kind of load balancing of the datanodes when fetching the data. Can you also provide some references and what algo it uses by default? I have tried googling and going through the documentation but never found anything.

Answer (score 0):

The namenode is contacted for HDFS block locations; it can pick any replica of a block to return to the HDFS client, all blocks are considered equal, so yes it "load-balances", but it prefers node-local or rack-local (assuming you are using YARN) over remote lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not using YARN. How does it pick one of the replicas? Random? or any known policy? Also, I haven't seen any mention of this load balancing in any documentation. Can you provide any references?

Comment: The Spark executor get ran in a YARN nodemanager. The nodemanager process is commonly running on the same servers as the datanodes. Therefore, HDFS requests are "local" to the execution. If the file isn't found, then extra network requests are sent to external servers. It's not called load balancing because it's possible a select few datanodes have the majority of the data you need, so more requests will be sent to them